# Is it possible to get email address of twitter user in android? If yes, then how?

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm new to android development. I used the following code to access the email address of my personal twitter account, but it does not work for me. 

**I am using this code**:

```
TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();

authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void success(Result result) {
        // Do something with the result, which provides the email address
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
      // Do something on failure
    }
});
```

Comment: Refer this https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/request-user-email-address.html

Comment: Thanks ! but i have already used this code. but i'm not able to get email address. I don't know how is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requesting a User’s Email Address requires your application to be white listed by Twitter. To request access, you can visit

https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.

See the query posted in [twitter community](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-can-i-get-email-address-after-login-to-twitter-im-using-fabric-sdk-android/61599) for more.

> **N.B :**  Even if the user grants access to her email address, it is not
>   guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone
>   signed up for Twitter with a phone number instead of an email address,
>   the email field may be empty. When this happens, the failure method
>   will be called because there is no email address available.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try.